# Synchronize two filters

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I have two widgets with buttons which I want to synchronize. If I press a button on the first widget I can fire the corresponding event of the second widget but the selected button of the second widget doesn't change. Any way to automate this?

And is it possible to synchronize widgets (buttons and filters) over several reports?

Comment: Could you please clarify about "several reports". Are you using embedded reports or you have just several reporting instances on your page?

Comment: The reports are not embedded, my page has several reporting instances.

Answer (score 0):

All filter widgets have to event handlers that we need:

- **on Selection** - fire event on selection change
- **do Set Selection** - consume event and provide selection on it's own options

Example:

Create two filters and configure similar query options.
After that you should configure Events for the first filter like in the screenshot: 
[image]

and second Filter's event options are

[image]

And after this your widgets will work as desired.

Comment: This works for MDX Filters, but not for Tools/Utilities like action buttons which only have `on Button Click`, `on Selection`, and `do Resize Widget` events.

Comment: Sorry not yet possible to do that for 'Tools/Utilities' widgets.